# Iterate and print element values upto range n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function for the following code and make it in a way that I can iterate up to 'n' elements:

```
t1 = np.array([dataset[0].x, dataset[0].y])
t2 = np.array([dataset[1].x, dataset[1].y])
t3 = np.array([dataset[2].x, dataset[2].y])

l = ((loc[0].x, loc[0].y), (loc[1].x, loc[1].y))
d = (np.linalg.norm(t1 - t3), np.linalg.norm(t2 - t3))
i = (guess.x, guess.y)
```

Following is how I have started writing the function:

```
COUNT = 3
def func(self, dataset, loc, guess):
    dataset = []
    l = []
    d = []

    for i, j in itertools.product(range(COUNT), range(COUNT - 1)):
      dataset.append(np.array([dataset[i].x, dataset[i].y]))
      l.append((loc[j].x, loc[j].y))
    d = ((np.linalg.norm(dataset[0] - dataset[2])), (np.linalg.norm(dataset[1] - dataset[2])))
    i = (guess.x, guess.y)
    print(f"dataset: {dataset}\n\nl: {l}\n\nd: {d}")
```

Following is how the values are getting printed when I run the new function where elements are getting repeated:

```
dataset: [array([1.08507621, 4.52543869]), array([1.08507621, 4.52543869]), array([7.17810676, 4.60046099]), array([7.17810676, 4.60046099]), array([7.17835665, 4.60035314]), array([7.17835665, 4.60035314])]

l: [(-0.097, 3.0), (6.0, 3.0), (-0.097, 3.0), (6.0, 3.0), (-0.097, 3.0), (6.0, 3.0)]

d: (6.093492401630743, 6.093492401630743)
```

Can someone help me figure out how to fix it? Also appreciate any suggestions if this can be written in a better way. I want the function to work even when COUNT is incremented to n number.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you called the function? What were the inputs, and what was the expected output? Also, please include your import statements (multilaterate() is not a standard python command)

Comment: Why are you using a product when appending when all you need is a single range since the `dataset` and `loc` indices should be the same for each element, but for `d` you don't use that product?

Comment: I have remove `multilaterate` from the code since that's not relevant... and starting indices are same for `dataset` and `loc` but `dataset` iterates through the last index (in this case 0 to 2) and `loc` iterates through the last but prev index (0 to 1). That's why I added a product.